# Configure the Asus DD-WRT through command line

Tags: dd-wrt

I have a dd-wrt running on a Asus RTN66U AP.

Are there any commands that I can run through the command line by telnet-ing into the AP to configure different security and in WPS mode

The goal is to try to automate the AP configuration for WPS and different securities

Comment: WPS is totally broken.  You may as well not bother to enable WIFI security.

Answer (score 1):

The tool/command you are looking for to modify settings is "nvram" - see https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Hardware

```
nvram show
```

will dump the variables and contents, while

```
nvram set variable_name="value"
```

will set the value.

You need to then run nvram commit to save the changes.

As a starting point, grepping the output of nvram on my ddwrt box (which is a RT-AC68U, so similar), the following settings include details you may want to change:

```
wl1_wds0=*,auto,aes,psk2,5GSSIDNAME,5GPASSWORD
wl0_wpa_psk=PASSWORD
wl1_wpa_psk=PASSWORD
wl0_wds0=*,auto,aes,psk2,SSIDNAME,PASSWORD
```

Again, don't enable WPS - [its broke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Setup#Vulnerabilities) and can't be fixed.